# Como eu crio uma tabela desse jeito bem assim mesmo

Tags: html5

deve ser bem bobo meu problema mais estou tendo dificuldade

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UI2c.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando `colspan`, se você pretende que uma coluna (`<td>`) especifica ocupe o espaço equivalente a 3 colunas então sete na coluna desejada `<td colspan="3">`, se fosse para ocupar o espaço de 4 colunas seria `<td colspan="4">`

Exemplo:

```css
.tabela, .tabela td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.tabela {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabela">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Atendimento</td>
            <td colspan="3">Público</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pres</td>
            <td>Tel</td>
            <td>Email</td>

            <td>Est</td>
            <td>Prof</td>
            <td>Out</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>

            <td>SP</td>
            <td>Foo Bar</td>
            <td>Baz Bar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Note que usei só `<tr>` e `<td>`, mas você pode separar o que é o "header" da tabela e usar TH, que seria mais por questão de semântica (também poderia usar combinado com o atributo `scope=""`, o que pode ser interessante para combinar um CSS para customizar, mas isto é outra história):

```css
.tabela, .tabela td, .tabela th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.tabela {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Atendimento</th>
            <th colspan="3">Público</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Pres</th>
            <th>Tel</th>
            <th>Email</th>

            <th>Est</th>
            <th>Prof</th>
            <th>Out</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>

            <td>SP</td>
            <td>Foo Bar</td>
            <td>Baz Bar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: meu obrigado era isso mesmo...... to tendo tarde toda fazia tempo que não usava tabela vlw mesmo

Comment: @kauajotta obrigado. PS: acaso queira que uma coluna ocupe duas linhas ou mais (que seria o inverso da resposta) o atributo é `rowspan` ;)